# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a procedure in SQL Server 2008R2 but it is showing this error

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI"
>   and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

The procedure that I have created is

```
CREATE Procedure Ps_Quiz_OnlineTest_QuestionsWithOptions_Get --'Ques1'
  @Ques Varchar(8000)
As        
Begin

  Select 
    A.QuestionId, 
    A.QsnDesc, 
    A.CorrectOption, 
    B.OptionValue, 
    A.Marks,
    (
      Select QsnName 
      From Quiz_tblQsnsLimitMaster
      Where QsnId = @Ques) QuesPaper,
    (
      Select Durationoftest 
      From Quiz_tblQsnsLimitMaster
      Where QsnId = @Ques) QuesPaper
    From 
      Quiz_tblQsnCreationMaster A, 
      Quiz_tblQsnCreationDetail B        
    Where 
      A.QuestionId = B.QuestionId
      And A.QuestionId In (
        Select QuestionIds 
        From FN_Question_Answers_Quiz(@Ques))
      And B.QuestionId In (
        Select QuestionIds 
        From FN_Question_Answers_Quiz(@Ques))  
    Order By 
      A.QuestionId, 
      B.OptionOrder 

End
```

I tried to collate tables with different collations but it did not worked.
How can I solve this.

Comment: Add a `COLLATE` statement on the comparison for the table with the other collation. If you're running from SSMS, can double click on the error in the results window and it'll show you which line it occurred on :)

Comment: It is showing error on line 6 that is 
Select A.QuestionId, A.QsnDesc, A.CorrectOption, B.OptionValue, A.Marks,

How can I add COLLATE statement here?

Comment: What datatype is Quiz_tblQsnsLimitMaster.QsnId?

Comment: @Hanumendra it'll be on of the comparison operations somewhere. Are `A.QuestionId` and `B.QuestionId` of datatype varchar?

Comment: @Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić, datatype is Varchar

Comment: @Bridge, yes the datatype is varchar

Comment: Try collating two of your conditions `QsnId = @Ques COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Comment: @ Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić It is still showing the same error

Comment: @Hanumendra After taking Ozren's advice, did you double click on the error message again? It may be that you fixed one problem, and the error is occuring again on a different line.

Comment: @Bridge I did it, but the error still persists in the same line

Answer (score 15):

probably this might help, change your where condition like this

```
Where A.QuestionId COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = B.QuestionId  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you've mentioned that QuestionID in each table is varchar, it's probably the comparison between those. So at a guess, try changing the line:

```
Where A.QuestionId = B.QuestionId  And
```

To the following:

```
Where A.QuestionId = B.QuestionId COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS And
```

I'd prefer it if you used proper join syntax for your tables - but that's for another day ;-)

Comment: I tried it, but its not working, it is showing the same error

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following syntax when joining tables with different collations,

```
where  A.QuestionId collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI__AS = B.QuestionId collate
SQL_Latin1_General1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 1):

try use this,
where fieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = secondfieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

this is working

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this use the below code:

```sql
SELECT NAME
FROM sys.objects
WHERE NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT IN (SELECT TYPE  
FROM sys.objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue after migration of Database and shifting of server by service provider. So as solution I have created new database using CPanel then execute SQL query for schema and data to restore. Finally this issue got resolved.