# Table variables errors in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server stored procedures, sometimes I'm getting an error while using table variables and comparing them with data in the table variables and it is showing error sometimes and sometimes not. And sometimes an error will be produced in the local database and server database it does shows error

[image: screenshot of the error]

I have found some solutions like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` on both sides of the comparison from some answers in StackOverflow

But want to know the root cause of the issue and want the permanent solution to it

Kindly please help me to find the correct solution to it

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077815/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-latin1-general-ci-ai-and-sql-la

Comment: table variable will use the database collation. Apparently your database collation is different with whichever table that you are comparing with. Use the same collation or cast it explicitly to resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

You have to make both columns with the same Collate so we can compare.
change collate of your columns to collate `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` from `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

```
SELECT     BTable.*
FROM       ATable INNER JOIN BTable
ON ATable.cid  = BTable.id collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Thank you @Seyed Raouf Modarresi , I know the solution of the issue as "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" but want to know root causes which are producing these issues, can you explain me in clearly

Comment: But my reputations  are less than 15, so my Votes aren't calculated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Database collation is the same on local and Server Databases. And then you can apply the code solution to both environments, say

```
select * from A join B on A.Name = b. Name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

(When the DB collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)